# Combining IN array within MSSQL Query using CASE

Tags: sql-server, string

I have the following block of code that works well, and I am trying to (unsuccessfully) update it, here is what I have so far:

```
CASE
    WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NOT NULL AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)>30) THEN 'OK'
    WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NOT NULL AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)>0) AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)<=30) THEN 'Warning'
    WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NOT NULL AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)<=0) AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)>-30) THEN 'Warning'
    WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NOT NULL AND (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), GasSafeExpiry)<=-30) THEN 'Alert'
    ELSE ''
END AS GassafeStatus,
```

What I want, is to add another condition that if the GasSafeExpiry field is null and another field equals or contains 3, then the result is "Missing", I have tried this:

```
    WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NULL AND 3 IN (SubcontractorType) THEN 'Missing'
```

Unfortunately that does work and returns a syntax error, so I am assuming it is not the right method.  Essentially the SubcontractorType field is a numeric string, and is a combo box of 7 options, linked by FK, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, so I want this to work for any instance where 3 appears in the array and if the expiry field is null.

I am getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3,5' to data type int.

Comment: `ELSE '' THEN 'Alert'` can't be correct. The `else` part doesn't have a `then` part associated with it.

Comment: `WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NULL AND 3 IN (SubcontractorType) THEN 'Missing'` is valid in solitude; though the latter clause is equivalent to `3 = SubcontractorType`. The `CASE` you've shown, in addition to what @ZoharPeled states, also has *two* `ELSE` clauses; it can only have one.

Comment: Thanks, i'd just spotted that myself and corrected it, unfortunately now getting this, Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3,5' to data type int.

Comment: Because you're expecting a value like `'3,5'` to act as **two** values; it's a *scalar* value. The *real* problem here is your denormalised design; you should really be fixing that and *not* storing delimited data in your database.

Comment: In other words a string that happens to contain comma-delimited values is still just a string, it doesn't magically becomes an array just because it's inside the parenthesis of the `in` operator

Comment: Also, arrays don't exist in T-SQL. The closest you get to arrays are tables, which are completely different.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the comments, but dont have any control over the design of the database, so still in need of a workaround

Comment: you probably want: `WHEN GasSafeExpiry IS NULL AND CHARINDEX(',3,', ',' + subcontractortype + ',') > 0  THEN 'Missing'`